# MongoDB - Get documents by their last embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I'm facing an issue. I'm currently creating an app that runs tasks. Some tasks may cause errors. In that case, I store in my mongo db the status of my task.

I wanna create a job that load every errored tasks and rerun them.

See the data structure:

```
{
    {
        _id: 1,
        actions: [
            {
                "name": "action_1",
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:54.000",
                        "status": "pending"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:56.000",
                        "status": "running"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:58.000",
                        "status": "passed"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        actions: [
            {
                "name": "action_1",
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:54.000",
                        "status": "pending"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:56.000",
                        "status": "running"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:58.000",
                        "status": "error"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        actions: [
            {
                "name": "action_1",
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:54.000",
                        "status": "pending"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:56.000",
                        "status": "error"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:56.000",
                        "status": "running"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:58.000",
                        "status": "passed"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 4,
        actions: [
            {
                "name": "action_1",
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:54.000",
                        "status": "pending"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:56.000",
                        "status": "error"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:56.000",
                        "status": "running"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:58.000",
                        "status": "passed"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "action_2",
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:54.000",
                        "status": "pending"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2017-08-04 15:37:56.000",
                        "status": "error"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I wanna do is to load only documents that have their last embedded document (and only the last) `actions.statuses.status` to `error`.

Finally the query will return documents with ids `2` and `4`.

Is there a way to say "only the last embedded document" ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Nesting arrays is not a great idea for a number of reasons, so you really do need to change that. Also last array index is also not a great idea and it would be better to use `$position` when updating an make sure the most recent is always the "first" element by "pre-pending" to the array instead. Because it's dead easy to look for the `0` index of an array

Comment: Point being. Do it like I'm saying there, and it's simple query and we can even use indexes. Do it how you are currently doing it, and the only way to get a result is by essentially scanning the whole collection and slicing off the last array element to see if it matches your condition. That's not a good thing to do. So it's better to "reverse" the array.

Comment: You can sort your embded documents by `date` field or sort using $natural:1 and take the last one.

Comment: @NeilLunn Store in reverse order is a good option that allow me to build my query more easily; Thanks :D (How could I not think of it LMAO)

Comment: $where can be used but that's a bad solution since it will be a full collection scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @NeilLunn solution, I store the statuses in reverse to build my query with the `0` position like this : `db.my_collection.find({"actions.0.statuses.0.status": "error"})`

Thanks to him !